# How can a person return distinct tuples where a column has a new formula applied to it in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Using mySQL...

I'm trying to return distinct tuples that include the id, name, and GPA only,
where the gpa follows this new formula:

GPA = sum(numerical grade * credits) / sum(credits)

(So I am returning the grade for each class including credits so that I have the info I need to calculate the formula above. I want to just return the id, name, and GPA having the GPA use the formula above.)

I.E. for Zhang It would look like:

```
for each tuple where ID = 00128
{ GPA = GPA * credits / totalCreditsForThisStudent; }
```

I have gotten this far:

Here is my SQL Statement and result:

```
SELECT id, name, (
CASE 
WHEN grade LIKE 'A' 
then 4.0
WHEN grade LIKE 'A-' 
then 3.67
WHEN grade LIKE 'B+' 
then 3.33
WHEN grade LIKE 'B' 
then 3
WHEN grade LIKE 'B-' 
then 2.67
WHEN grade LIKE 'C+' 
then 2.33
WHEN grade LIKE 'C' 
then 2
WHEN grade LIKE 'C-' 
then 1.67
WHEN grade LIKE 'D+' 
then 1.33
WHEN grade LIKE 'D' 
then 1
WHEN grade LIKE 'D-' 
then 0.67
WHEN grade LIKE 'F' 
then 0
END) as GPA, credits 
FROM student natural join takes natural join course
WHERE grade is not null
;


Output:
id      name    GPA     credits
00128   Zhang   4.00    4
00128   Zhang   3.67    3
12345   Shankar 2.00    4
12345   Shankar 4.00    4
12345   Shankar 4.00    3
12345   Shankar 4.00    3
19991   Brandt  3.00    3
23121   Chavez  2.33    3
44553   Peltier 2.67    4
etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you want distinct records so much as aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    id
    , name
    , SUM(
            (
                CASE 
                    WHEN grade LIKE 'A' 
                        then 4.0
                    WHEN grade LIKE 'A-' 
                        then 3.67
                    WHEN grade LIKE 'B+' 
                        then 3.33
                    WHEN grade LIKE 'B' 
                        then 3
                    WHEN grade LIKE 'B-' 
                        then 2.67
                    WHEN grade LIKE 'C+' 
                        then 2.33
                    WHEN grade LIKE 'C' 
                        then 2
                    WHEN grade LIKE 'C-' 
                        then 1.67
                    WHEN grade LIKE 'D+' 
                        then 1.33
                    WHEN grade LIKE 'D' 
                        then 1
                    WHEN grade LIKE 'D-' 
                        then 0.67
                    WHEN grade LIKE 'F' 
                        then 0
                END
            ) 
        ) / 
        SUM(credits)
        as GPA
FROM 
    student 
natural join 
    takes 
natural join 
    course
WHERE grade is not null
GROUP BY 
    id
    , name
;
```

Comment: That is amazing help! I had to add to each case the * credits. I.E. then 4.0 * credits. But you totally answered my question!